# Windows "Double-Shortcuts" for batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

In Windows we can create a shortcut for any batch script and assign a shortcut for it. (Right-Click on shortcut->Properties->Shortcut key)

How can I assign a double-shortcut for a shortcut like this? For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in a sequential order I want the batch script to execute.

Is this possible in Windows? If this method doesn't work, is there any other method this can be achieved through?

Comment: I'm curious about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a script to be executed when i press for example "Ctrl+Alt+J" and "Ctrl+Alt+K" in sequential order.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I'm trying to understand why you want to do it. Why do you need to press two hotkeys?

Comment: because i'm running out of shortcuts and i need more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, assigning a combination of hotkeys is impossible. Windows shortcuts are essentially stored [IShellLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects. The object's [GetHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation shows that only a single hotkey can be used.

Perhaps you could try [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Although I have no experience with it, AHK is usually the solution for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key which will give you more combinations of keys.

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+***key***
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+***key***
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+***key***
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+***key***